# Remove an item with certain property value from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given a list of objects, where each has a property named `x`, and I want to remove all the objects whose `x` property contains value `v` from the list.

One way to do it is to use list comprehension: `[item for item in mylist if item.x != v]`, but since my list is small (usually less than 10). Another way is to iterate through the list in a loop and check for every single item.

Is there a third way that is equally fast or even faster?

Comment: If the list is small, you shouldn't care about the speed at all. Write whatever is more readable.

Comment: both ways you described are functionally identical. why do you need a third way? also, if your list is small, there is no practical reason to make it faster.

Comment: The 'iterate through and remove' option is generally a terrible idea, as you either have to iterate by index (cumbersome, slow and ugly) or use `list.remove(value)`, which then means you will iterate over the list for each value, massively increasing the complexity of what you are doing. A list comprehension (or generator expression) is the best solution here.

Comment: And, as others have said, for ten items, it simply won't matter. Just do what is most readable (probably the list comp), and move on. Premature optimization is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a **generator** or the `filter` function. Choose what you find the most readable; efficiency doesn't really matter at this point (especially not if you're dealing with just a few elements).

Answer (score 1):

Create a new list using list comprehension syntax. I don't think you can do anything faster than that. It doesn't matter that your list is small, that's even better.